# Rails String Replace URL Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a string like:

```
url = "https://example.com/user/tr_auth.php?key=34432&cmp_id=344&tr_id={user_id}"
```

I want to update the `cmp_id=344` to be say `cmp_id=44553`. What's the best way to accomplish this? I can't gsub per say because I don't know what cmp_id might be equal, only that it will be a URL parameter in the string.

It seems like I want to do something like

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
```

But then, how do I re-build the string swapping out the `cmp_id` parameter to be `44553`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are dealing with a web application (and/or Rails as the tag seems to indicate), then you certainly have Rack available. [`Rack::Utils`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Utils) has methods to parse and build a query.

```
url = "https://example.com/user/tr_auth.php?key=34432&cmp_id=344&tr_id={user_id}"
uri = URI.parse(url)

query = Rack::Utils.parse_query(uri.query)
# => {"key"=>"34432", "cmp_id"=>"344", "tr_id"=>"{user_id}"}

# Replace the value
query["cmp_id"] = 44553

uri.query = Rack::Utils.build_query(query)
uri.to_s
# => "https://example.com/user/tr_auth.php?key=34432&cmp_id=44553&tr_id=%7Buser_id%7D"
```

Also note that Rack, by default, escapes the query.

Answer (score 2):

```
url = "https://example.com/user/tr_auth.php?key=34432&cmp_id=344&tr_id={user_id}"
uri = URI.parse(url)
params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
params['cmp_id'] = 44553

new_str = uri.host + uri.path + '?' + params.to_query
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can parse the url for params:

```
require 'cgi'
url = 'https://example.com/user/tr_auth.php?key=34432&cmp_id=344&tr_id={user_id}'
string_params = url.split('?')[1]
hash = CGI::parse(string_params)
```

Then you can iterate the hash by keys and change values:

```
hash.keys.each {|key| hash[key]='new value'}
url_params = hash.to_param
```