# How to remove substring that may appear within a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to simplify url strings for some reporting, and sometimes our url strings have `gclid` params baked into them at different parts:

`https://www.website.com/colors/blue?src=camp_id1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoInnBRDDARIsANBVyASfVUCg4ShKaAq4q8cX6xgB4kYj-oRGEPuO5UuUaAnZi2zD7yQU684aAo3KEALw_wcB`

or

`https://www.website.com/colors/blue?gclid=Cj0KCQjwoInnBRDDARIsANBVyASfVUCg4ShKaAq4q8cX6xgB4kYj-oRGEPuO5UuUaAnZi2zD7yQU684aAo3KEALw_wcB&src=camp_id1`

or

`https://www.website.com/colors/blue?page=2&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoInnBRDDARIsANBVyASfVUCg4ShKaAq4q8cX6xgB4kYj-oRGEPuO5UuUaAnZi2zD7yQU684aAo3KEALw_wcB&src=camp_id1`

or

`https://www.website.com/colors/blue?page=2&src=camp_id1`

So there are all these variations of the URL.  Sometimes they contain the `gclid` and sometimes they don't.  They're often at different parts in the url.

What's the easiest way in ruby to print the string without the `gclid` substring if it's there?

Answer (score 3):

```
.sub(/[\?&]gclid=[^&]*/, '')
```

Comment: It's not necessary to escape a question mark within a character class.

Comment: Keep in mind that, from an educational point of view, you are instructing readers (who don't read comments :-)) that a question mark within a character class *must* be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the base URL you can do:

```
url = your_url_string
trimmed_url = url[0, url.index("?")]
```

Or you can guard against strings without query params:

```
url = your_url_string
trimmed_url = url[0, (url.include?('?') ? url.index("?") : url)]
```

There may be a way to do it with `URI` as well...

If all you need to do is remove that parameter, see this answer: [Rails String Replace URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965927/rails-string-replace-url-parameters)

Comment: I need to keep the other params, but just get rid of the gclid.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the URI library for this instead so you can just parse the query portion:

```
uris = ["https://www.website.com/colors/blue?src=camp_id1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoInnBRDDARIsANBVyASfVUCg4ShKaAq4q8cX6xgB4kYj-oRGEPuO5UuUaAnZi2zD7yQU684aAo3KEALw_wcB",
"https://www.website.com/colors/blue?gclid=Cj0KCQjwoInnBRDDARIsANBVyASfVUCg4ShKaAq4q8cX6xgB4kYj-oRGEPuO5UuUaAnZi2zD7yQU684aAo3KEALw_wcB&src=camp_id1",
"https://www.website.com/colors/blue?page=2&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoInnBRDDARIsANBVyASfVUCg4ShKaAq4q8cX6xgB4kYj-oRGEPuO5UuUaAnZi2zD7yQU684aAo3KEALw_wcB&src=camp_id1",
"https://www.website.com/colors/blue?page=2&src=camp_id1"
]

uris.map do |s| 
  uri = URI.parse(s)
  query_params = uri.query.scan(/\w+(?==)[^&]*/).reject{|s| s.start_with?('gclid')}
  uri.query = query_params.empty? ? nil : query_params.join('&')
  uri.to_s
end

# => ["https://www.website.com/colors/blue?src=camp_id1", 
#     "https://www.website.com/colors/blue?src=camp_id1", 
#     "https://www.website.com/colors/blue?page=2&src=camp_id1",  
#     "https://www.website.com/colors/blue?page=2&src=camp_id1"]
```